# How to add osx modelbox plugin to all the div's - jquery

Tags: jquery, html, plugins

below is the code

More »

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  Integer varius

Close

jQuery(function ($) {
    var OSX = {
        container: null,
        init: function () {
            $("a.more-replay1").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

```
            $(".osx-modal-content1").modal({
                overlayId: 'osx-overlay',
                containerId: 'osx-container',
                closeHTML: null,
                minHeight: 80,
                opacity: 65, 
                position: ['0',],
                overlayClose: true,
                onOpen: OSX.open,
                autoPosition: true,
                onClose: OSX.close

            });
        });
    },
    open: function (d) {
        var self = this;
        self.container = d.container[0];
        d.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function () {
            $(".osx-modal-content1", self.container).show();
            var title = $(".osx-modal-title", self.container);
            title.show();
            d.container.slideDown('slow', function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    var h = $(".osx-modal-data1", self.container).height()
                        + title.height()
                        + 80; // padding
                    d.container.animate(
                        {height: h}, 
                        200,
                        function () {
                            $("div.close", self.container).show();
                            $(".osx-modal-data1", self.container).show();
                        }
                    );
                }, 300);
            });
        })
    },
    close: function (d) {
        var self = this; // this = SimpleModal object
        d.container.animate(
            {top:"-" + (d.container.height() + 90)},
            500,
            function () {
                self.close(); // or $.modal.close();
            }
        );
    }
};

OSX.init();
```

});

it's working fine for one div with content, i want to same js for n number of div...

Comment: Can you show your attempt and highlight what particular issue you are having?

Comment: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/  i downloaded through this link, there only show demo with one content, i need it for multiple content with referring same id/class for all div's....

Comment: So you haven't actually tried to adapt it yourself? Most people will not be willing to assist you unless you can show that you have put in some effort yourself.

Comment: sorry ren, i already applied for my website, which im doing locally, but i add the js multiple time, so i need to optimize that anyway...